# SQL query not showing desired result with multiple AND and OR clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

My following query is not showing desired result. I don't understand where I am using the brackets wrong

Query:

```
SELECT `orders`.*, `users`.`fullname`, `users`.`phone`
FROM `orders`
JOIN `users` ON `orders`.`userId` = `users`.`id`
WHERE `orders`.`payment_verified_status` = '1'
AND (`orders`.`restId` = 132 OR `orders`.`restId` = 133 OR `orders`.`restId` = 134)
AND (`rest_brId` != 156 OR `rest_brId` != 188 OR `rest_brId` != 157 OR `rest_brId` != 691 OR `rest_brId` != 158)
```

The result is coming:
[image]

But these rows shouldn't come because I have mentioned in the query that `rest_brId != 156`

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Imagine that you were google searching for your exact problem. Would you google "SQL query not showing correct result"? Try rephrase your question so that it is specific

Comment: you did, but you also said " OR rest_brId != 188", and that's true in that row, as are all the others, so overall the AND clause is true, so it returns the row. NOT IN is your friend here.

Comment: `A != 1 or A != 2` will be true for `A = 1` because the expression `A != 2` is true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `in`:

```
SELECT o.*, u.`fullname`, u.`phone`
FROM `orders` o JOIN
     `users` u
     ON o.`userId` = u.`id`
WHERE o.`payment_verified_status` = 1 AND
      o.`restId` IN (132, 133, 134) AND
      ?.`rest_brId` NOT IN (156, 188, 157, 691, 158)
```

Note the `?`.  This is for the talbe alias for `rest_brID`.

The problem with your logic is the `OR` for the not-equals, not the parentheses.  That part of the logic always evaluates to true, because you actually want `AND` instead of `OR` for that portion of the logic.

Answer (score 2):

This part of your `WHERE` clause is incorrect:

```
(`rest_brId` != 156 OR `rest_brId` != 188 OR `rest_brId` != 157 OR `rest_brId` != 691 OR `rest_brId` != 158)
```

If `rest_brId = 156`, although the first part of the clause is not true, the second through fifth parts (e.g. `rest_brId != 188`) are true, so the row gets into your output. You need to change that line to:

```
(`rest_brId` != 156 AND `rest_brId` != 188 AND `rest_brId` != 157 AND `rest_brId` != 691 AND `rest_brId` != 158)
```

or use a `NOT IN` clause as @GordonLinoff suggests.